# Can preprocessor directives be used outside of code files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c-preprocessor

Can the [C# preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx)  be used in other than code files?

I know how to use them in Code files, here is the example from the MSDN-Pages:

```
// preprocessor_if.cs
#define DEBUG
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use `#if` in XML (or other non-code) files to have different data for debug and release? For example:

```
<coustomXml>
#if DEBUG
    <item>debugdata</item>
#else
    <item>releaseData</item>
#endif
</coustomXml>
```

I tried this with the app.config of my project, but the compiler ignores the flags.

Comment: if your xml processor has been extended with a c# preprocessor, then yes.  But, since that's unlikely, no.  You can write an xslt transform to do this though.

Comment: I don't use an xml processor, the xml-file is part of my visual-studio project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use compiler directives, but you can use config transofrmations based on the build type:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx